# Fading in a body background on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now, I'm using switchClass to change the body backgound.  The change is instant and not easy on the eyes.

```
$('.Click').click(function () {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var st = thisClass.split(' ');
    var firstClass = st[0];

    if (firstClass == "item1") {
        $('.mask').animate({
            marginLeft: "-100%"
        }, 600, function () {
            $("body").switchClass($("body").attr("className"), "bg1");
        });
    } else if (firstClass == "item2") {
        $('.jobsMask').animate({
            marginLeft: "-200%"
        }, 600, function () {
            $("body").switchClass($("body").attr("className"), "bg2");
        });
    }
});
```

How do I animate this / make this less abrupt?

Comment: Instead of manual parsing of the class string and relying that `.item1` is the first in the string you may use `.hasClass()`

Comment: Are you working with background images rather than colours?

Comment: I'm working with images.

Comment: "...animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels ..."

Comment: hey OP, see my edited answer - I added a solution for fading bg images as well as colours. Note that in Chrome, the first solution works (but the second solution doesn't hurt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For `background-color` fading:**

You can use a transition on the `body` element to animate changes to the `background` property like this:

```
body { 
  -ms-transition: background 0.8s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.8s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: background 0.8s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.8s ease 0s;
  transition: background 0.8s ease 0s;  
}
```

test it: http://jsbin.com/odabit/2/edit

---

**For fading background images:**

Transitions don't seem to work on `background-image` (EDIT: they work in Chrome, but not in Fx16, Opera12.1, or IE9), so my workaround is to put your bg images on separate divs, and then fade those in and out, like this: http://jsbin.com/odabit/7/edit

The switching code looks like this:

```
var cls1 = 'bg1', cls2 = 'bg2',
  body = $('body'),
  bg1 = body.hasClass(cls1) ||  !!body.children('.'+cls1)[0],
  bg = bg1 ? body.children('.'+cls1) : body.children('.'+cls2),
  newBg;

if (!bg[0]) {
bg = $('<div>', {'class': (bg1 ? cls1 : cls2)}).prependTo(body);
}

newBg =  $('<div>', {'class': (bg1 ? cls2 : cls1)}).insertAfter(bg).hide();

body.removeClass(cls1 +' ' +cls2);

bg.fadeOut('slow', function() { bg.remove(); });
newBg.fadeIn('slow');
```

And the CSS to support it:

```
body > div[class^="bg"] {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg1 {
  background: url(/* image 1 */);
}

.bg2 {
 background: url(/* image 2 */); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to!  http://jsbin.com/odabit/5/edit  But, I think I got a (messy) fix.

Comment: That explains it!  Works for me in Chrome too - just not Fx, Opera, or IE9.

Comment: Nice answer.  How do you extend this to have multiple BGs and specific css selectors calling on them?

Comment: Put your various bg class names in an array and search through that to find (or create, if it doesn't exist yet) the currently visible bg element. Insert after that a new bg element holding your next image (how you decide what's next is up to you), then fade out/in the old/new bg elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add css transitions to all attributes within the class, or use this:

```
$("body").switchClass($("body").attr("className"), "bg2", 1000);
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/).

I am assuming here that your classes differ in background color. If they have different background images, transitioning between them is not as simple.

Comment: `.switchClass` doesn't work with changing background images.  I tried this with different durations.

Comment: @SpYk3HH yes, since `switchClass` is used in the question, I don't believe it is unreasonable to assume he is using jquery-ui.